# HuggingFace download file size

Tags: download, config, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

Models from 'transformers' library has `from_pretrained()` method that saves weights in *.bin files. The default max file size is ~9GB. Each .bin file can contained multiple sets of weights as explicitly specified in 'pytorch_model.bin.index.json'. In the following example `pytorch_model-00001-of-00009.bin` contains 16 sets of weights/biases.

```
 "transformer.h.0.ln_attn.bias": "pytorch_model-00001-of-00009.bin",
"transformer.h.0.ln_attn.weight": "pytorch_model-00001-of-00009.bin",
"transformer.h.0.ln_mlp.bias": "pytorch_model-00001-of-00009.bin",
"transformer.h.0.ln_mlp.weight": "pytorch_model-00001-of-00009.bin",
"transformer.h.0.mlp.dense_4h_to_h.weight": "pytorch_model-00001-of-00009.bin",
"transformer.h.0.mlp.dense_h_to_4h.weight": "pytorch_model-00001-of-00009.bin",
"transformer.h.0.self_attention.dense.weight": "pytorch_model-00001-of-00009.bin",
"transformer.h.0.self_attention.query_key_value.weight": "pytorch_model-00001-of-00009.bin",
"transformer.h.1.ln_attn.bias": "pytorch_model-00001-of-00009.bin",
"transformer.h.1.ln_attn.weight": "pytorch_model-00001-of-00009.bin",
"transformer.h.1.ln_mlp.bias": "pytorch_model-00001-of-00009.bin",
"transformer.h.1.ln_mlp.weight": "pytorch_model-00001-of-00009.bin",
"transformer.h.1.mlp.dense_4h_to_h.weight": "pytorch_model-00001-of-00009.bin",
"transformer.h.1.mlp.dense_h_to_4h.weight": "pytorch_model-00001-of-00009.bin",
"transformer.h.1.self_attention.dense.weight": "pytorch_model-00001-of-00009.bin",
"transformer.h.1.self_attention.query_key_value.weight": "pytorch_model-00001-of-00009.bin",
```

I was wondering if there is a way to change the default download scheme to save the model in a greater number of smaller files?